How to add a new category to a Polars column?
I have a categorical column in Polars with 3 categories 'A', 'B' and 'C', inferred from a training dataset. The column also contains some nulls.
Now suppose there exists a previously-unseen category 'X' in my test set. I want to handle it like this:

Add an 'Unknown' category to the training column
For any unseen categories in test set (e.g. 'X'), set them to 'Unknown'.
Keep all nulls in train and test sets as-is (or as a dedicated category), since they may have special meaning.

How to accomplish this?

Are you working with pl.Categorical, pl.Enum or pl.String?

It sounds like the categories you'd like to use ("A", "B", "C", and "Unknown") are known up front. In this case, pl.Enum should be used.
Let us consider the following sample data.
import polars as pl

df_train = pl.DataFrame({
    "cat": ["A", "B", "C"],
})

df_test = pl.DataFrame({
    "cat": ["A", "X", "C"],
})

Based on the training data, a pl.Enum datatype including an additional category "Unknown" can be created as follows.
enum_dtype = pl.Enum(
    df_train.get_column("cat").unique().drop_nulls().append(pl.Series(["Unknown"]))
)

Note. .drop_nulls() is used (although the data in this example doesn't contain nulls) as precautionary measure since Enum categories cannot contain null values.
Now, the categorical column in the training dataframe can be casted directly to the pl.Enum datatype.
df_train.with_columns(pl.col("cat").cast(enum_dtype))

shape: (3, 1)
┌──────┐
│ cat  │
│ ---  │
│ enum │
╞══════╡
│ A    │
│ B    │
│ C    │
└──────┘

For the test dataframe, this would fail as "D" is not a known category in the pl.Enum datatype. Here, using strict=False can be used to cast unknown categories to None. Subsequently, missing values can be replaced with the category "Unknown".
df_test.with_columns(
    pl.col("cat").cast(enum_dtype, strict=False).fill_null("Unknown")
)

shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────┐
│ cat     │
│ ---     │
│ enum    │
╞═════════╡
│ A       │
│ Unknown │
│ C       │
└─────────┘

Edit. If the test data already contains missing values that should be kept as such, unknown values can be explicitly replaced with "Unknown" before (strict) casting.
df_test.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col("cat").is_not_null() & ~pl.col("cat").is_in(enum_dtype.categories)
    ).then(
        pl.lit("Unknown")
    ).otherwise(
        pl.col("cat")
    ).cast(enum_dtype)
)


Thanks! It works to some extend until I was hit by a TypeError: Enum categories must not contain null values (while running enum_dtype = pl.Enum(df_train.get_column("cat").unique().append(pl.Series(["Unknown"])))), which is due to existence of null values in my training data. I want to keep those nulls as-is (since I suspect they have special meaning), and only assign unseen categories ('X') in test set to 'Unknown'. How to do this? Edited the question.

@lpounng Glad it helped. I've edited my answer to address the issue of missing values.

Thanks again, but there seems some miscommunication - my issue is that the training data contains nulls, and Enum does not like it.

@lpounng I see. In this case, you can define enum_dtype using all categories except None: enum_dtype = pl.Enum(df_train.get_column("cat").drop_nulls().unique().append(pl.Series(["Unknown"])))

Just to clarify, a column of values of Enum type is allowed to contain nulls, just the categories of the Enum type itself can not.

thanks @orlp for the clarification, it completed Hericks's answer.
